# EDA, creating boxplot, histogram and etc from very large numpy arrays, phython

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have a dataset (as a numpy memmap array) with shape (37906895000,), dtype=uint8 (it's a data collection from photocamera sensor).
Is there any way to create and draw boxplot and histogram with python? Ordnary tools like matplotlib cannot do it - "Unable to allocate 35.3 GiB for an array with shape (37906895000,) and data type uint8"

`plt.boxplot(data)`
seaborn, matplotlib crashes with "Unable to allocate 35.3 GiB for an array with shape (37906895000,) and data type uint8". The same with pandas dataframe.